# <VirtualHost> error in Apache2.conf

Tags: apache2, lamp

I cannot fix this without asking for help. On install of LAMP via Syn. Pkg. Mgr. and trying to setup and run LAMP, I have received:

```
mark@Lexington:/$ apachectl restart
/usr/sbin/apachectl: 87: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
apache2: Syntax error on line 237 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.com: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.com:1: <VirtualHost> was not closed.
```

The /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file talks about a `<VirtualHost>` and I have read examples of what to put there, but I'm not able to understand what I am doing. And since the file says DON'T unless you know what you are doing, I am asking:

1. This is XUbuntu 12.04. I tried installing LAMP. The purpose of this is to run vnstat in a browser and see the bandwidth usage. Also, I want to "serve" a mp3 file to a weblog I keep. I don't understand why I would make an Apache error log visible in a browser. I would have little reason to see the bandwidth usage at another location. The only other reason for LAMP is I am trying to use MythTV to send the TV signal to a "smart" tv via ethernet cable.
2. If you can point me towards a URL or other help, I'm much obliged.
3. If you can give me the name of a text editor that shows line numbers so I can look at "line 237" I'll try to figure the syntax error.

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. This is more server configuration/maintenance.

Comment: vim, nano, gedit (this is a gui).  The easiest for you will probably be nano.  Do `nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and scroll to line 237 to see what's going on

Answer (score 0):

oh, this looks easy...i think.  You'll see `<VirtualHosts>` near or at the top of the file `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.com` (error says line 1).  Scroll down through everything.  if you do not see `</VirtualHosts>` (notice the slash), put that in the bottom of the file.  Save and close, then restart apache

Regarding the "operation not permitted": you may have to use `sudo` to elevate your privileges (assuming you are on unix, which i think you are).  Research how to do this if you don't know.